# How to access the database imported through datapump

Tags: oracle10g, datapump

I just imported  data dump through below command:

```
IMPDP user/pass FULL=Y DUMPFILE=BIRDV24012014.DMP LOGFILE=BIRDV24012014.log;
```

The dump has been restored the issue is i dont know how to connect to this database that i just imported, what service or TNS does it resides and how can i query it?

Comment: It may also be a good idea to check 'BIRDV24012014.log'

Answer (score 1):

You didn't import a database, you imported the contents of your file into your existing database. If you could successfully run `impdp user/pass` then your `ORACLE_SID` etc. is already set and you should be able to log in and query with `sqlplus user/pass`.

If you've come from another RDBMS background you may be confusing 'database' with 'schema'. Depending on what was in the dump, you've probably created a load of schema objects and data under the `USER` schema or whatever your real '`user'` value was).

The import makes no difference to this, but if you want to access the database from another client (e.g. from another machine, or over JDBC) then you'll need to check your listener configuration to get the hostname/IP address and port it's listening on, and get the service name for the database; all of which can be obtained from `lsnrctl services` if you have permission to run that. You can then use those values for a JDBC URL, or in a `tnsnames.ora` entry, or ODBC, etc.

Comment: Yes, It looks FULL=Y has created all schema(s) and its objects under CURRENT database (SID). Schema 'USER' looks a privileged user as it was able to run impdp.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your `ORACLE_SID` environment variable. There you'll find the instance ID. If you ran the IMPDP tool as user Oracle, you should also be able to connect to the database using

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

If all fails, look at your `/etc/oratab` file to see which instances are available on this host.

On another note, your command seems incomplete. Datapump requires a `DIRECTORY`parameter to know where to look for the dumpfile you specified.

Comment: ok ill check, i have kept my dump file in the default direct of `dpdump` so it automatically picked it

Comment: Ah yeah, `DATA_PUMP_DIR` is the default folder. Forgot about that one.